# Rational sequence less than constant rational sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, rational-numbers, cauchy-sequences

Let $X$ be the set of Cauchy rational sequences. Let $(q_n)\in X$. Show that there exists $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $(q_n)<(q)$.

Here one needs to show the following:

There exists a rational number $q$ satistfying

- $(q_n)\le (q)$, which means that $0<\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $q_n \le q + \epsilon$ whenever $n\ge N$;
- $(q_n)\not\sim (q)$, which means that $\exists 0<\epsilon_0\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\forall N\in\mathbb{N},\exists n\ge N_{\epsilon_0}$ satisfying $|q_n-q|\ge \epsilon_0$.

It looks like the first part is quite straightforward, but I got stuck in Part II.

**Part I:**

Since $(q_n)$ is Cauchy, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N_\epsilon \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|q_n-q_m|\le\epsilon$ for all $m,n \ge N_\epsilon$. Fix $q_{N_\epsilon}$, then $|q_n-q_{N_\epsilon}|\le \epsilon$, which means that

$$q_n\le q_{N_\epsilon}+\epsilon$$

**Part II:**

Suppose there is no $\epsilon_0$ satisfying the above condition. Consider $\epsilon_0 <\epsilon$, then $N_{\epsilon_0}\ge N_{\epsilon}$. Let $n\ge N_{\epsilon_0}$, then

$$|q_n-q_{N_{\epsilon}}|\le |q_n-q_{N_{\epsilon_0}}|+|q_{N_{\epsilon_0}}-q_{N_{\epsilon}}|<\epsilon_0+\underbrace{|q_{N_{\epsilon_0}}-q_{N_{\epsilon}}|}_\text{:=k}=\epsilon_0+k$$

That's where I'm stuck. How can I complete my proof by arriving at a contradiction?

Comment: $(q_n)<(q)$ means $(q_n)\le(q)$ and $(q_n)\not\sim (q)
$?

Comment: @mechanodroid Exactly.

Comment: A Cauchy sequence is bounded so let $M \in\mathbb{Q^+}$ be such that $|q_n|+1<M$. Now obviously $(q_n) < (M)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: The way you proved it assumes that we already know that Cauchy sequences are convergent (and thus bounded). Here the idea is to show that the two notions above are satisfied.

Comment: You can show it is bounded without using that it converges in $\mathbb{R}$: there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m, n \ge N \implies |q_n - q_m| < 1$. For $n \ge N$ we have $|q_n| \le |q_n- q_{N}| + |q_N| < 1 + |q_N|$. So $(q_n)$ is bounded by $\max\{|q_1|, |q_2|, \ldots, |q_{N-1}|, |q_{N}| + 1\}$.

Comment: True. Yours is a nice way. I'd appreciate if you could also suggest how to get over the obstacle in my Part II. I think your proof is more straightforward, but I'd still like to understand if there is a way around my obstacle there.

Comment: Your Part I. is wrong because you have to find $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that **for every** $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ we eventually have $q_n \le q + \varepsilon$. If you choose $q_{N_\varepsilon}$ then there is no guarantee that you will eventually have, say, $q_n \le q_{N_\varepsilon} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. So you cannot prove it that way.